# How to count characters excluding new lines in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, count

I would like to count the number of characters in Swift. I'm using this code

```
let charsNumber = str.characters.count
```

It returns the number of characters and returns. Is there a way I can count just the characters without the returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter(isIncludedIn:)` to exclude something from a Sequence:

```
let str = "abc\ndef\nghi"
let charsNumber = str.characters.filter {$0 != "\n" && $0 != "\r"}.count
print(charsNumber) //-> 9
```

If the `str` is very large, this may be a little more efficient:

```
let charsNumber = str.characters.lazy.filter {$0 != "\n" && $0 != "\r"}.count
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions(rawValue: 0), range: nil).characters.count
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use String method enumerateLines to sum the characters count of your string lines as follow:

```
let str = "abc\nabc\nabc\n"
var charsNumber = 0
str.enumerateLines { line, _ in charsNumber += line.characters.count }

print(charsNumber)   // 9
```